# Filtering an array inside an object inside an array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to filter an array, which is inside an object, itself inside an array in React. But it still returns the full array. How could I fix this?

This is my code:

```
const [allArtists, setAllArtists] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("url")
        .then((res) => {
            setAllArtists(res.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}, [])

for (let i = 0; i < allArtists.length; i++) {
    allArtists[i].available.filter((date) => new Date(date) >= new Date())
}
```

And the array:

```
[
    {
        "available": [
            "2022-05-26",
            "2022-04-21",
            "2022-05-16",
            "2022-09-16",
            "2022-06-21",
            "2022-08-19",
            "2022-11-14",
            "2022-08-20",
            "2022-09-29",
            "2022-03-22",
            "2022-11-02",
            "2022-05-03",
            "2022-11-07",
            "2022-01-11",
            "2022-01-12"
        ]
    },
    {
        "available": [
            "2022-09-09",
            "2022-08-03",
            "2022-01-20",
            "2022-09-04",
            "2022-07-17",
            "2022-04-07",
            "2022-08-17",
            "2022-06-19",
            "2022-04-12",
            "2022-05-27",
            "2022-03-12",
            "2022-02-5",
            "2022-04-18",
            "2022-01-19",
            "2022-05-10"
        ]
    }
]
```

I also tried to put the for loop inside another useEffect, but it wasn't working either...

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Is the expectation here that once you apply `available.filter` the elements in the `available` array will be mutated?

Comment: Try to collect the `filtered` array separately. And then, update using `setAllArtists`.

Comment: Something like so: `setAllArtists(prev => (prev.map(({available, ...rest}) => ({rest, available: available.filter(d => ((new Date(d) >= (new Date()))))}))));`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not assigning your filtered results to anything.

Your loop could be changed to something like this:

```
const result = allArtists.map(({ available }) => available.filter((date) => new Date(date) >= new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I could use it like this and it's working:

```
setAllArtists(
    res.data
        .map(({ available, ...artist }) => {
            return {
                available: available.filter(
                    date => new Date(date) >= new Date()
                ),
                artist,
            }
        })
)
```